# Why doesn't include_page work in Liferay 6.2 (FreeMarker 2.3.17)?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker, liferay-theme

I am trying to include an html page in my [liferay](https://www.liferay.com/it/third-party-software) theme in *portal_normal.ftl* using the **FreeMarker** [`<@include_page path="..."/>`](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#pgui_misc_servlet_include) directive:

```
<@include_page path="${full_templates_path}/page.html" />
```

but I get this error:

```
on line 153, column 81 in theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/portal_normal.ftl include_page not found.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> user-directive include_page [on line 153, column 81 in theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/portal_normal.ftl]
----------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include_page` is not a core FreeMarker directive, but a custom directive provided by `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet`. Unless Liferay uses that (which I highly doubt), that's why that directive doesn't exist.

(BTW, Liferay 6.2 ships with 2.3.17 from 2011? That's sad.)

Comment: Thank you so much @ddekany but I have seen in `%liferay%\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\freemarker.jar` in `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` this constant `KEY_INCLUDE = "include_page"` so I suppose that this directive exists in liferay 6.2 CE GA3.

Comment: `FreemarkerServlet` is part of the FreeMarker package, but it doesn't mean that it's used.

Comment: Thanks! I will post the question in [Liferay Forums](https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/70352183) on how to use `FreemarkerServlet` in Liferay.